# asymptotic form of divisor bound

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, proof-explanation, asymptotics

Let $d(n)$ denote the divisor function, the number of divisors of $n$. Following this post of Tao, https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/ I have managed to show that $d(n) \leq C_{\epsilon}n^{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

I want to show this is equivalent to $d(n)=n^{o(1)}$ but am not sure how to do so.

I know that $f(x)=o(g(x))$ means that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$. I'm not sure how to proceed because in the above the "little oh" is an exponent.

I did think about taking logs but I don't know if this is allowed with asymptotic notation or if that then helps as I'd then having to show $\frac{\log(d(n))}{1} = 0$ (I've assumed I could "absorb" the $\log(n)$ into the "little-oh").

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing slightly, we want to show that $d(n) = O_\epsilon(n^\epsilon) \iff d(n) = n^{o(1)}.$ I write $O_\epsilon(\cdot)$ to indicate that the implicit constant is allowed to depend on $\epsilon$, as you've written $C_\epsilon$ in the question.

Let's look at the direction for $\implies$

To show that $d(n) = n^{o(1)}$, we need to show that for any $\delta > 0$, there is some $N_\delta$ such that for all $n > N_\delta$, we have that $d(n) < n^\delta$. From $d(n) = O_\epsilon(n^\epsilon)$, we can take $\epsilon = \delta/2$, say. Thus we know there is some $N_\epsilon$ such that $d(n) < C_{\delta/2} n^{\delta/2}$ for all $n > N_\epsilon$. This is almost what we want, except for the constant $C_{\delta/2}$. But the point of choosing $\epsilon = \delta/2$ is that for sufficiently large $N$ (call this point $N_C$), we have $C_{\delta/2} < n^{\delta/2}$ for all $n > N_C$.

Combining together, for all $n > N_\delta := \max\{N_\epsilon, N_C\}$, we have that $d(n) < C_{\delta/2}n^{\delta/2} < n^{\delta}$, exactly as we wanted to show.

The $\impliedby$ direction is substantially similar. More concisely, we know $d(n) = n^{o(1)}$ and we want to show $d(n) = O_{\epsilon}(n^\epsilon)$. In analogous notation to above, take $\delta = \epsilon$, so that $d(n) < n^\delta = n^\epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$. This is precisely what we wanted to show, with the constant $C_\epsilon = 1$.